# OUT parameter with multiples values

Tags: oracle, plsql, parameters

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  Show_R(A IN VARCHAR2, B OUT VARCHAR2) 
    IS 
    BEGIN
    select func_w(day),TO_CHAR(hour, 'HH24:MI')INTO B
    from task t
    inner join mat m
    on t.id_p = m.id_a
    where m.cod_mod = A; 
    END;
```

I have a issue with this code, this select gets two types of columns data that are not the same type of data, i don't know how to add into B two types of data in only one "out parameter"

Answer (score 0):

You can't put 2 values into 1 OUT parameter. So, use 2 OUT parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly don't store `day` and `hour` in separate columns. Just use a single `DATE` column as, in Oracle, the `DATE` data type has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components and so can store both the date and time.

Secondly, don't use `A`, `B`, `show_R` or `func_w` identifiers; use meaningful names as it will be far easier to debug your code in 6-months if you can tell what it is intended to do.

Third, your `SELECT ... INTO` statement will fail as you have two columns but only one variable to select into; you need 2 variables in `INTO` clause and this means (unless you are going to concatenate the two values) that you need 2 `OUT` parameters.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE Show_w_day_and_hour(
  i_cod_mod IN  mat.cod_mod%TYPE,
  o_w_day   OUT VARCHAR2,
  o_hour    OUT VARCHAR2
) 
IS 
BEGIN
  SELECT func_w(day),
         TO_CHAR(hour, 'HH24:MI')
  INTO   o_w_day,
         o_hour
  FROM   task t
         INNER JOIN mat m
         ON ( t.id_p = m.id_a )
  WHERE  m.cod_mod = i_cod_mod; 
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0f3741a189ae4bf0dfcddd47f2639ea0)